# puppet 4.9.4 "import" Evaluation Error

Tags: puppet, vagrant-provision

having the following issue while running vagrant provision using puppet:

> Use of 'import' has been discontinued in favor of a manifest directory

in Vagrant file i mentioned

```
puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests/development'
```

the issue i stuck with happens when applying the next string from "rails_service.pp" manifest:

`import "service_user.pp"`

the manifest "service_user.pp" lays in the same folder as "rails_service.pp" /puppet/modules/web/manifests

I tried to use `include` instead and got the error:

> Could not find class ::web::service_user

web::service_user.pp has the following code:

```
define web::service_user(
  $user_name,
  $user_home,
  $user_id="not_needed",
  $user_groups = [],
  $services_root="/",
  $service_name,
  $environment
  ) {...}
```

And if I use `class` instead of `define` I got the error:

```
> Error while evaluating a Function Call, Class[Web::Service_user]:
==> dev:   expects a value for parameter 'user_name'
==> dev:   expects a value for parameter 'user_home'
==> dev:   expects a value for parameter 'service_name'
==> dev:   expects a value for parameter 'environment'
```

however, the code is:

```
include web::service_user
  web::service_user { 'balance-checker-user' :
    user_name => 'balance_checker',
    user_groups => ['pools_app_group'],
    user_home => '/opt',
    service_name => 'balance_checker',
    environment => $environment,
  }
```

Comment: `import` has been discouraged in Puppet for years. You cannot pass parameters directly to a class when using `include`. Try removing the include and the import statements and returning `web::service_user` to its defined resource type.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, thanks for the explanation. But how it will look like if `import` and `include` are removed?

Comment: It will look like what you wrote above except the line with the include will not exist.